# is there a way to run commands in python on windows?

Tags: python

I am trying to execute a command as below using python in windows and running into 
`WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified` error, ,currently I do not have `script.exe` on my PC , manually running it throws the error `'script.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`,I would expect the same error to be thrown running through python,how to fix this error?really appreciate any inputs

CODE:-

```
cmd = "script.exe"
print "Executing " + cmd
fetchPipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(output, error) = fetchPipe.communicate()
```

Comment: you need to use the full path to `script.exe` is the easiest answer... or pass in the environment PATH variable ... or pass `shell=True`, but there are some security implications with that

Comment: If the file don't exist, you can try as hard as you can, it won't start. That's the base of nonexistent element. You need to provide a full path to your software/script you want to run inside of the cmd variable. (Note that relative paths works too, but are a lot harder to use since you must know where the file is located from your script.

Comment: @JoranBeasley  and Artemis - I cant give the absolute path as `script.exe` is not in a specific location,it can be anywhere in the PATH variable,so passing in the environment PATH variable looks like the way,how do I pass in the environment PATH variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def find_abs_path(executable_fname):
    if os.path.exists(executable_fname): # in case it is in our cwd
        return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(".",executable_fname))
    for dirname in os.environ["PATH"].split(";"): # split dependant on your os
        if executable_fname in os.listdir(dirname):
           return os.path.join(dirname,executable_fname)
```

should search your path and find the absolute path to the executable

this is the recommended way of doing it ...

...*however* you can pass in an env

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd_args,env=os.environ,...)
```

this should supply the same PATH variable to the subshell that runs ... as such it can probably find the executable ...

Comment: what if the executable is present in multiple places in environment variable,which location would it return?

Comment: the same one your shell would find if you just typed the executable name in the shell directly ... (the first one on the path ...)

Answer (score 2):

You have to choose between one of these solutions:

1. pass the `relative path` and set the current working directory to the same folder that contains script.exe by using `os.chdir('folderPath')` before trying to open the file

OR

2. pass the `absolute path` to the `script.exe` file by using `cmd = os.getcwd() + "\\script.exe"`

By using the **second approach**, you'll have:

```
cmd = os.getcwd() + "\\script.exe"
print "Executing " + cmd
fetchPipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(output, error) = fetchPipe.communicate()
```

Comment: I cant give the absolute path as script.exe is not in a specific location,it can be anywhere in the PATH variable,so passing in the environment PATH variable looks like the way,do you suggest any other way?

Comment: actually there is the option of passing the (poorly-documented) `env` argument